# how can i use RegExp to grap data from this site?

Tags: regex

i want to grap data from this site by regexp

http://aymanalrefai.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/596/

i tried this

```
/<div class="entry">.*?<p class="postinfo">/is
```

but it didn't give me a correct result

any help ?

Comment: 1. Don't use regex to parse HTML. It's unreliable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. 2. Your regex matches for me, but I can't tell what a "correct result" is unless you tell us.


  [1]:

Comment: i want to grap the internal box
which starts with <div class="entry">  and ends with <p class="postinfo">

i tried my regex
but it gives me Initialization.... only
is it a problem with wordpress ?

Comment: What tool/language are you using ? Are lazy quantifiers available there ? Does it require escaping quotes ?

Comment: That regex works for me.  What do you mean when you say it gives you "initialization"?

Comment: i am using Joomla and using component called econtent  which grab data from rss 
i put this regex...but it gives me  "initialization" and no response

it may be a problem with wordpress
http://aymanalrefai.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/596/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

/<div class="entry">**[\s\S]**+?</div>/is